# increment id number for next/prev links

Tags: php, increment

I've got a mysql table with an auto incremented ID field in it. When I loop for output to the page, I start the output for each iteration with the following so I can refer back to it via an anchor in the url:

```
// after query and while loop
<a name="'.$row['id'].'"></a>
```

What I'd like to do is to have a next/prev style link in each iteration that grab the $id, increments it by one and parses a link, if there is a next or prev $id, something like this:

```
// query then loop
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

// increment $id to create var for NEXT link
$n = intval($row['id']);
$next = $n++;

// decrement $id to create var for PREV link
$p = intval($row['id']);
$prev = $p--;

// output PREV link
if($prev > intval($row['id'])) {
    echo '<a href="page.php#'.$prev.'">Previous</a> | ';
} else {
    echo 'Previous | ';
}

// output NEXT link
if($next < intval($row['id'])) {
    echo '<a href="page.php#'.$next.'">Next</a>'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Next'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

But using the above returns nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$next = ++$n;` and `$prev = --$p;`. Moreover, both of yours if-comparisons are incorrect, they won't work. Say, your $row['id'] is 5, then $prev will be 4, and the condition `if (4 > 5)` gives false

Answer (score 0):

```
    You are using post increment and decrement but you need to pree increment and decimeter
Example
$x=5;
$y=$x++;
echo $y; //Output will be 5

// increment $id to create var for NEXT link
    $n = intval($row['id']);
    $next = ++$n;


    // decrement $id to create var for PREV link
    $p = intval($row['id']);
    $prev = --$p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change it to either -

```
$next = $n+1;
$prev = $p-1;
// adds/subtracts 1 from $n/$p, but keeps the same value for $n/$p
```

or

```
$next = ++$n;
$prev = --$p;
// adds/subtracts 1 from $n/$p, but changes the value for $n/$p to ++/--
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

When you do

```
$next = $n++;
$prev = $p--;
```

The increase/decrease will not occur until after the line of code is executed

Also, your comparison operators (<>) need to be flipped. Try -

```
// increment $id to create var for NEXT link
$n = intval($row['id']);
$next = $n+1;

// decrement $id to create var for PREV link
$p = intval($row['id']);
$prev = $p-1;

// output PREV link
if($prev < $p) {
    echo '<a href="page.php#'.$prev.'">Previous</a> | ';
} else {
    echo 'Previous | ';
}

// output NEXT link
if($next > $n) {
    echo '<a href="page.php#'.$next.'">Next</a>'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Next'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note -
`if($prev < intval($row['id']))` & `if($next > intval($row['id']))` will always return TRUE.
What you should be checking for is if `0 < $prev < intval($row['id'])` and `intval($row['id']) < $next < max id`

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that it's sorted by ID DESC (actually by date_added DESC, but that's a different story), so I switched up the > and < and it works great, EXCEPT that it still displays links for Prev and Next when none exist, so the final if statement is still giving me some grief.

Comment: You need to get the first & last id's, not check against `$row['id']`. The way I do this is I do a min/max query - `SELECT MIN(id) AS min, MAX(id) as max FROM table` - then I use those in my if - `if($prev > $min)` & `if($next < $max)`